# What is the jQuery/javascript function for this purpose

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var arr = [{
    name: "abcd",
    type: "1 kg"
}, {
    name: "efgh",
    type: "1 cai"
}, {
    name: "ijkl",
    type: "1 kg"
}];
```

I want to retrieve `type`  if I know the `name`

so,

```
name_function('abcd') will return 1kg
```

Comment: so there is not any build-in function for mapping purpose?

Comment: No, there isn't. If you want to mape names to values, use a single object.

Comment: how to use a single object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built-in function that searches an array like this. If you want to do mapping, you normally use a single object, not an array of objects.

```
var map = {
    "abcd": "1 kg",
    "efgh": "1 cai",
    "ijkl": "1 kg"
};
```

Then you can get the mapping using `var type = map[name];`.

Answer (score 1):

**Go with Barmar answer**. There are no inbuilt function to get the type in array object. Otherwise use **for loop** in javascript

```
var arr = [{
    name: "abcd",
    type: "1 kg"
}, {
    name: "efgh",
    type: "1 cai"
}, {
    name: "ijkl",
    type: "1 kg"
}];

function getType(val) {
  var type;
  for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
     if(arr[i].name === val){
         type = arr[i].type;
         break;
      }
  }
  return type;
}
```

Comment: Use `break` when you find the element with the matching name.

Answer (score 0):

you can try [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
console.log( arr.filter( function(x){ if (x.name=="abcd") return true; } ).type );
```